# Call web service in interval on background

Tags: android

Application need synchronize data from server in interval (for example every 30min) or manually on background. Result is saved to local database. After sync is done I want remind activity/fragment ... and force update list (if needed). There are many activities, so I want move it outside of activity and make it more consistent.

For now I created AsyncTask which get result from server and save to DB.

What shoud I use? BroadcastReciever, Service, AlarmManager?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on answers I start **alarm** in Application

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

Created **Receiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent syncIntent = new Intent();
        syncIntent.setClass(context, DataSyncer.class);
        startWakefulService(context, syncIntent);
    }
}
```

Created **IntentService**

```
public class DataSyncer extends IntentService {
        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // get data from server
            // save to DB
            AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
}
```

And registered Receiver and Service in **AndroidManifest**

```
<service
    android:name="com.cloudit.tsystems.app.DataSyncer"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>
<receiver
    android:name="com.cloudit.tsystems.app.AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
</receiver>
```

Where and how I notify that sync is done in Activity/Fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the AlarmManager and register a BroadcastReceiver. Once the receiver is fired, I will launch an IntentService to download the data in the background.

Configure your alarm:

```
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
```

Create a BroadcastReceiver that will get notified when the alarm goes off. Note that I'm using a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) so that the device doesn't go to sleep when you're syncing.

```
class MyBroadcast extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent syncIntent = new Intent();
        syncIntent.setClass(context, DataSyncer.class);
        startWakefulService(context, syncIntent);
    }
}
```

Next, an IntentService that will download data in the background:

```
class DataSyncer extends IntentService{

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       //sync data
       MyBroadcast.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

**Update:**
So now that you have your data synced, there are several options to notify Activities and Fragments. You can use a LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast. Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html) link for more details.

Comment: Where I configure alarm? In `BroadcastReciever` and add to manifest or just in 1st activity after started app?

Comment: I prefer to configure the alarm in the Application class. You can configure it in the Activity, but since you're Activity can get recreated on config changes, you may end up setting the alarm frequently.
Yes, you should register the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest.

Comment: So, I tried register `Service` and `BroadcastReciever` in code and manifest, but its invoke just once or twice, maybe I should define `intent-filter` or what is wrong :/

`<service android:name="com.cloudit.tsystems.app.DataSyncer"></service>` & `<receiver android:name="com.cloudit.tsystems.app.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>`

Comment: @WindsurferOak i am having the same issue,i have a usecase where in i have to make a webservice call in background,which should call indefinitely or in some timegap and show the updates has a notification and on click of notification it opens the app and shows the updated list..i went through this post but i am getting will this suffice my usecase?

Answer (score 1):

Use an AlarmManager to trigger a PendingIntent on a 30 minute interval that starts an IntentService to do your download.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, PollingService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
                pendingIntent
);
```

When the IntentService is done updating your data, it can send a Broadcast that your Activity/Fragment has registered to listen for to notify it of new data and refresh it's view.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("DATA_UPDATED"));
```

In your Fragment

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //update UI
        }
    }, new IntentFilter("DATA_UPDATED"));
```

Comment: I updated question, your answer helped me, but you register receiver in activity/fragment ... so only way to notice activity/fragment is create inner class and register there? or I can create receiver outside of a/f? Sry for nooby questions but im still confused in using receivers and services.

Comment: You can create an application wide receiver but if your Activity/Fragment is the thing that cares about it so that it can update the UI, you will want it to register for the broadcast event.  Probably in the onResume() method.  And unregister in the onPause()