# android Use service or use alarm manager

Tags: java, android, json, service, alarmmanager

I have an application that downloads some data from a webservice using json. 
I want that when the user does not have the application open, my application connects to webservice and ask if there is new data show, and if so throw a notification, and download new data. 
Now my question. Do you recommend creating a service and say that every X seconds call json looking for an update? , Recommend Or use the alarm manager class? 
Any better ideas? 
Do any tutorial important? 
thank you very much

Comment: There's a similar question [here][1] that shows you how to do this. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001143/call-web-service-in-interval-on-background/23001227#23001227

Comment: You might be interested in that new thread : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23007924/693752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use alarm manager that will be trigger at every time X... execute the download..

Why? because if you use services it might be closed at some point and you might end up skipping some updates at a certain time (unknown).

Or just use service knowing that it is ok if its get close at certain point by the system fto free the ram and restart again after.